# Is it possible to develop a video conferencing app for Google TV?

Tags: android, google-tv

First off, I've done some research but I can't find anything on this topic. I figured someone here might be knowledgeable enough to assist. My company is researching the compatibility of video conferencing for a project. Is it possible to see someone else's camera on your screen while the other person sees your camera on their screen on Google TV? What kind of protocols are supported? What kind of resolution and bandwidth are we talking about? I would appreciate the help. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Its definitely possible, but a huge undertaking (you'd need to write the networking code to send the data across, etc).  Out of scope for stackoverflow I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We announced our next release at Google I/O and it will support NDK and that should be shipping sometime later this year.  You will probably want to use cameras that do encoding in the camera for now.